# I'm trying to export all the data from my replit db

Tags: pandas, export-to-csv, replit-database

I'm currently trying to move a tonne of data out of replit db by converting it into CSV using pandas

Is it to do with how the data is stored into the db? Is it a mistake to treat the db like a dictionary?

I tried this

```
Data = pd.DataFrame(db) 
Data.to_csv('data.csv')
```

I only get the keys and not the actual data.

i.e.

```
, 0
1, key1
2, key2
3, key3
```

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Overflow. What does your data look like before and after dataframe creation? Add the results of  `print(db)` and `print(Data.head())` to the question, so we can get a better picture on what's happening.

Comment: when i use print(db) i get the url and when i do print(Data.head()) i get a name error

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please include your module imports. Please insert your above comment's information into your post. `db` can indeed be treated as a dictionary so let's see `db.keys()` and `db.values()`. I take it that you are familiar with the tips in [What is Replit Database?](https://docs.replit.com/hosting/databases/replit-database) ?

Comment: It seems like "key1" is the value of db at key "1" and so on and so forth. Am I reading this wrong? But maybe let's not care about the csv export yet and focus on db object.

Comment: Yeah turns out I can't export db into CSV in a file explorer type of format. I thought I could do that. The way I am working around is by creating seperate files for each key as not all keys can be exported into CSV for my context

Answer (score 0):

Yeah turns out I can't export db into CSV in a file explorer type of format. I thought I could do that. The way I am working around is by creating seperate files for each key as not all keys can be exported into CSV for my context.

What do I mean by file explorer format? I thought I could export it in such a way that when I reference the CSV I can call it like a dictionary. But not all the data stored in each key was in dictionary format. Some were list, bunch of text or ints

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).